# jquery table search; how can I have the search ignore togglable rows and prevent toggling automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is an example of a table with input forms inside toggle-able hidden rows that I'm trying to get to behave properly.

As you can see, I have hidden rows that contain a text input and a submit button.

When you enter in keywords in the search input, the filter expands the hidden row, as well as expands all the hidden rows if you clear the search input.

I need to be able to have the search function not expand/show the hidden rows, yet have the hidden rows still be accessible when you click on the vote link to show the row.

It would also be nice to have the search function hide any of the hide/show rows that have been toggled previously when a new search is entered.

https://jsfiddle.net/zoo6mvso/1/

```
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search">
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <th><b>Item</b>
        </th>
        <th><b>Price (Dollars)</b>
        </th>
        <th><b>Price (Euros)</b>
        </th>
        <th><b>Vote</b>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cheese Burger</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="toggler" data-prod-cat="1">Vote</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cat1" style="display:none">
        <td colspan="4" style="white-space: nowrap">Enter Cheeseburger Price:
            <input type="text" maxlength="4" name="quantity" value="" class="input" />&nbsp;<a href="#" class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Burrito</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="toggler" data-prod-cat="2">Vote</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cat2" style="display:none">
        <td colspan="4" style="white-space: nowrap">Enter Burrito Price:
            <input type="text" maxlength="4" name="quantity" value="" class="input" />&nbsp;<a href="#" class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Pizza</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="toggler" data-prod-cat="3">Vote</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cat3" style="display:none">
        <td colspan="4" style="white-space: nowrap">Enter Pizza Price:
            <input type="text" maxlength="4" name="quantity" value="" class="input" />&nbsp;<a href="#" class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
</table>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $rows = $('#table tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});

    $(".toggler").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.cat'+$(this).attr('data-prod-cat')).toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't select the hidden `tr` elements when you find the tr elemnets

```
var $rows = $('#table tr:not(:hidden)');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cg978hgj/)

---

Another option is to dd a class to the hidden `tr` like

```
<tr class="cat1 hidden" style="display:none">
```

then

```
var $rows = $('#table tr:not(.hidden)');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cg978hgj/1/)

Comment: Hello, thanks much for the correction. 

Is there a way that the search could return the show/hide rows back to their default hide state when you enter or remove characters from the search input?